# Javascript standardjs - how to fix 'is already defined'?

Tags: javascript

What is the better to fix this 'error' of 'is already defined'?

```
function findOneAndUpdate (find) {
    var find = find || {}
     ...
}
```

The test from standardjs:

```
$ standard

... 'find' is already defined.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6+ solution with default parameters:

```
function findOneAndUpdate(find={}) { ... }
```

ES5- would be renaming:

```
function findOneAndUpdate (_find) { 
  var find = _find || {} 
  ... 
}
```

Otherwise, you can completely replace the variable, like other answers suggest:

```
function findOneAndUpdate (find) { 
  find = find || {} 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: love this solution!

Comment: but isn't `function findOneAndUpdate(find={}) { ... }`?

Comment: @teelou yes, missed a parenthesis

Comment: thanks for the edit! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to leave out the `var`, because the variable `find` is already declared through the method header:

```
function findOneAndUpdate (find) {
    find = find || {};
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just change either the function parameter name or the new variable's name?
The variable name `find` is clashing with the parameter `find`.

If all you want is give it an empty object as default parameter, you can safely reuse the parameter:

`find = find || {}`, just remove the `var`.