# es6 how to import already defined in another js package

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module, constants

I have a package that I use somewhat like this:

```
import { something } from 'somewhere';
```

But then I have another package that I import, and I need to define the same `something` name which is defined in it.

```
import myConsts from 'SomewhereElse';
const { something, another } = myConsts;
```

I get an eslint error (and rightly so) `something already defined`.

Here's a real example:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// following lines from react-native-kontaktio sample code...
import Kontakt from 'react-native-kontaktio';
const { connect, configure, startScanning } = Kontakt;
```

I tried

```
import { connect as kontaktConnect, configure, startScanning } from 'react-native-kontaktio'
```

but get `Possible promise rejection ... (reactNativeKontaktio.connect) is not a function`.

If I try to change the

```
import { connect as reduxConnect } from 'react-redux';
```

I'll have to change the export as follows. Won't that break my code elsewhere?

```
// export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppMain);
export default reduxConnect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppMain);
```

How can I overcome this?  Can I ignore the warning in some cases? There is no Polymorphism in Ecma6 right?

---

This is NOT [a question about two classes with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6), but about two classes with a method or a constant of the same name. 
The answer there seems to be applicable here, to use:

```
// instead of: import myConsts from 'SomewhereElse';
import { something as somethingElse, another } from 'SomewhereElse';
```

But then, when I use... `somethingElse().then(()=> ...`  I get an error  `Possible promise rejection ... (SomewhereElse.something) is not a function`

This also is NOT a [question about fixing the general `is already defined` eslint error] ([Javascript standardjs - how to fix 'is already defined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45999555/javascript-standardjs-how-to-fix-is-already-defined)), since I am not talking about writing MY code, but rather how to **import and use** someone else's two packages when they have this clash problem.

Comment: Why are you not using `import { connect, configure, startScanning }' from react-native-kontaktio'` directly?

Comment: according to their example. Is this old style?  Let me try. but won't that too clash with the redux connect?  How will the code know which to connect from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import two classes by the same name in javascript/es6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714947/how-to-import-two-classes-by-the-same-name-in-javascript-es6)

Comment: @feeela I edited question and explained why not duplicate

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal but then how will I write in the code and "know" which connect to use?   Is there anything in ec6 like namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No I think you can't ignore the warning, because 2 variables with the same name are present in the same scope.

You may need to import in this way:

```
import { connect as somethingElse} from 'react-redux';
```

To avoid to variables with the same name.

I hope it will help you

Comment: please see the update to my question which refers to this solution. If you can answer my problem in one of the two ways, i'll accept this answer.

Comment: @pashute 
_But then, when I use... somethingElse().then(()=> ... I get an error  Possible promise rejection ... (SomewhereElse.something) is not a function_
I think (I'm not sure) that as acts like an allias ... Are you sure that the error above is due to the use of 'as' ?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything. But in the end all worked out when I used an alias for the first one (in my case: redux)  and left the second const (in my case, for kontaktio) as is.